# RSA decryption error with PKCS#1: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 256 bytes

Tags: java, scala, encryption, private-key, public-key

I am running into this problem when trying to decrypt a message.

### Error

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort: Data must not be longer than 256 bytes 
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 256 bytes
```

My code is as follows.

```
package com.smth.what.api

import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec
import java.security.{KeyFactory, PrivateKey, PublicKey}

import javax.crypto.Cipher
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

object Encryptor {
  private val publicKeyString: String = System.getenv("PUB_KEY")
  private val privateKeyString: String = System.getenv("PRIV_KEY")

  private val publicKey = readPemPublicKey(publicKeyString)
  private val privateKey = readPemPrivateKey(privateKeyString)

  private def readPemPublicKey(publicKey: String): PublicKey = {
    val pemPublicKey = publicKey.replace("\n", "")
      .replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
      .replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
      .replace(" ", "")

    val publicKeyBytes: Array[Byte] = Base64.decodeBase64(pemPublicKey)
    val publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes)

    val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")

    keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec)
  }

  private def readPemPrivateKey (privateKey: String): PrivateKey = {
    val pemPrivateKey = privateKey.replace("\n", "")
      .replace("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
      .replace("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
      .replace(" ", "")

    val privateKeyBytes: Array[Byte] = Base64.decodeBase64(pemPrivateKey)

    val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")

    import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec

    import sun.security.util.DerInputStream

    val derReader = new DerInputStream(privateKeyBytes)
    val seq = derReader.getSequence(0)
    val modulus = seq(1).getBigInteger
    val publicExp = seq(2).getBigInteger
    val privateExp = seq(3).getBigInteger
    val prime1 = seq(4).getBigInteger
    val prime2 = seq(5).getBigInteger
    val exp1 = seq(6).getBigInteger
    val exp2 = seq(7).getBigInteger
    val crtCoef = seq(8).getBigInteger

    val keySpec = new RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec(modulus, publicExp, privateExp, prime1, prime2, exp1, exp2, crtCoef)

    keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec)
  }

  def encrypt(inputString: String, key: PublicKey = publicKey): String = {
    val cipher: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA")
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)

    new String(cipher.doFinal(inputString.getBytes("UTF-8")))
  }

  def decrypt(inputString: String, key: PrivateKey = privateKey): String = {
    val cipher: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA")
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key)

    val inputStringBytes = inputString.getBytes("UTF-8")

    new String(cipher.doFinal(inputStringBytes))

  }
}
```

My key's size is `2048`. It was generated via `openssl genrsa` with `.pem` output.

I use IntelliJ's environment variable to provide both public and private keys (via the Edit Configurations, copying and pasting them).

The error came from this line
`new String(cipher.doFinal(inputStringBytes))` from `decrypt` function.

I have been reading a few stackoverflow's posts (such as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262878/how-to-encrypt-aes-keys-using-rsa-without-running-into-javax-crypto-illegalbloc)), however, I still do not understand what is going on.

If possible, I would like a very basic explanation, as encryption/ decryption is a new area for me.

Comment: Are you sure that you are reading the propper values from the DER stream? According to [the spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017#appendix-A.1.2) or [this blog post](https://adangel.org/2016/08/29/openssl-rsa-java/) you may be missing some parameters. In addition, certain implementations may add further lines such as [outlined in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774469/how-does-the-rsa-private-key-passphrase-work-under-the-hood) to the key, especially when the key is encrypted. Here using one of an already existing library, such as BouncyCastle is probably safer to use

Comment: Using `String()` to try and hold arbitrary-valued byte arrays is a bug that results in corruption of data. If you must for some reason encode the encryption result as a String then use something like base-64 encoding. This code also contains the all-too-common Java crypto anti-pattern of `Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA")`. **Always** specify the full transformation string *algorithm/mode/padding*, never just *algorithm*.

Answer (score 1):

After attempting different things, what works is to apply `Base64` encoding to the encrypted message and then use `Base64` decoding when decrypting the encrypted message. This is aligned with what @James K Polk comment is saying.

See the updated code (only for the functions `encrypt` and `decrypt` as the rest remains the same)

```
  def encrypt(inputString: String, key: PublicKey = publicKey): String = {

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)

    val encrypted: Array[Byte] = cipher.doFinal(inputString.getBytes())

    Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted)
  }

  def decrypt(inputString: String, key: PrivateKey = privateKey): String = {

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key)

    val decodedInputString: Array[Byte] = Base64.decodeBase64(inputString)

    val decrypted: Array[Byte] = cipher.doFinal(decodedInputString)

    new String(decrypted)
  }
```